# On two-dimensional maximal commutative subalgebra of the complexification of the Heisenberg algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have considered the Heisenberg algebra $\mathfrak{h}$, of $3 \times 3$ real upper triangular matrices with zero diagonal, and its complexification $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}$, which turns out to be the space of $3 \times 3$ complex upper triangular matrices with zero diagonal.

I now consider a two-dimensional commutative subalgebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}$. I have proved that this is a maximal commutative subalgebra. Now, I want to prove that there is some $Z \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that the linear transformation $ad_Z : \mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}$ is not diagonalizable.

To see this, I first observed that the center of $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}$, which I will denote by $\mathfrak{z}$ is contained in $\mathfrak{g}$. Now, we know that the center $\mathfrak{z}$ is spanned b an element $H = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$. Let $X \in \mathfrak{g} \setminus \mathfrak{z}$. Then, $\mathfrak{g} = \text{span} \left\lbrace H, X \right\rbrace$. Clearly, there is some $Y \in \mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}} \setminus \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}} = \text{span} \left\lbrace H, X, Y \right\rbrace$.

Now, we notice that if we are to find an element $Z \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $ad_Z$ is not diagonalizable, then it would have to be a linear combination of $H$ and $X$. But since $H$ is in the center of $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}$, we have $ad_H = 0$. Therefore, $ad_Z = \alpha ad_X$, for some $\alpha \neq 0$. Hence, my guess is that $ad_X$ is not diagonalizable (because that is what we want to prove).

However, when we compute the action of $ad_X$ on the basis $\left\lbrace H, X, Y \right\rbrace$ of $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb{C}}$, we get

$$ad_X \left( H \right) = 0, ad_X \left( X \right) = 0, ad_X \left( Y \right) = \alpha H + \beta X + \gamma Y,$$

where at least one of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is non-zero. That is, the matrix of $ad_X$ in this basis is

$$ad_X = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & \alpha \\ 0 & 0 & \beta \\ 0 & 0 & \gamma \end{matrix} \right].$$

Hence, the eigenvlues of $ad_X$ are $0, 0, \gamma$ with the corresponding eigenvectors $H, X$ and $\left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\gamma} \right) H + \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\gamma} \right) X + Y$, provided $\gamma \neq 0$.

That is, if $\gamma \neq 0$, then clearly $ad_X$ is diagonalizable and so is $ad_Z$ for every $Z \in \mathfrak{g}$. Thus, I now want to prove that $\gamma = 0$. However, I am unable to do so. Any hints about this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct matrix computation shows that $[\pmatrix{0&*&*\\0&0&*\\0&0&0}, \pmatrix{0&*&*\\0&0&*\\0&0&0}] = \pmatrix{0&0&*\\0&0&0\\0&0&0} =\mathfrak z $ i.e. for any $x \in \mathfrak h_\mathbb C$, we have $ad_x(\mathfrak h_\mathbb C) \subseteq \mathfrak z$, i.e. in your notation, both $\beta, \gamma =0$.

More generally though, in a nilpotent Lie algebra $L$ (over $\mathbb C$, say) all $ad_L(x)$ are nilpotent, so if one of them is also diagonalisable, it is $0$, i.e. $x$ is in the centre of $L$. In other words, no $ad_L(x)$ in a nilpotent Lie algebra can be diagonalisable unless $x$ is in the centre of $L$.

Comment: Oh, right, yes! I missed that. I suppose I was too convinced that it has to do something with the basis I chose.